# Solving recurrence relation for running time of combination formula

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, recurrence-relation

I'm trying to solve the following Time complexity recurrence relation:

$T(n,k)=T(n-1,k-1)+T(n-1,k)+1$

that  come from following code:

```
int C(n, k) {
  if (k == 0 || k == n) return 1;  // stop recursion.
  return C(n-1, k-1) + C(n-1, k); 
}
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea to solve $T(n,k)$. Any hint that helpful be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $C(n,k) = T(n,k) + 1$. Then
$$ C(n,k) = C(n-1,k-1) + C(n-1,k). $$
This is exactly the recurrence of binomial coefficients, though there are also other solutions, for example $2^n$.

You can take the initial conditions to be $T(n,n) = T(n,0) = 1$, and so $C(n,n) = C(n,0) = 2$. You can check that
$$ C(n,k) = 2\binom{n}{k} $$
satisfies both the initial conditions and the recurrence relation. Hence
$$ T(n,k) = 2\binom{n}{k} - 1. $$

Comment: That's an exercise.

Comment: Thanks. For checking $C(n,k)=2\binom{n}{k}$, Can you more explain. what i do?

Comment: You can prove it by induction.

Comment: Excuse me, i each time try to prove $C(n,k)=2\binom{n}{k}$ , i get stuck. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: I use induction on $n$, but i can't relate $C(n+1,k)$ to $C(n,k)$, in essence , $C(n+1,k)=C(n,k-1)+C(n,k)$, now i can't relate $C(n,k-1)$ to previous terms.

Comment: Easily we can see $C(n,k)$ in $C(n+1,k)=C(n,k-1)+C(n,k)$, come from $C(n,k)$ and it's okay.

Comment: Use induction on $n+k$.

Comment: What is means Induction on $n+k$? Any induction proof i read is on one variable. unfortunately, $n+k$ for me is unclear. ohh you say, use induction on $n,k$? I test this but dosen't work for me.

Comment: Is induction on $n+k$. You prove the formula inductively for every value of $n+k$.

Comment: Thanks, now my argument as is follow: from base case we know that $C(n+k,n+k)=2\binom{n+k}{n+k}$, and it's valid. Now we want prove $C(n+k+1,n+k+1)=2\binom{n+k+1}{n+k+1}$ equal to: $C(n+k+1,n+k+1)=2\binom{n+k}{n+k}+2\binom{n+k}{n+k+1}$ right term equal to $0$ and left term is $C(n+k,n+k)$. Are my argument is true?

Comment: The sum of $n+k$ and $n+k$ is $2(n+k)$. The induction is on a statement $P(m)$ which states that whenever $0 \le k \le n$ and $k+n=m$ then $C(n,k)=2\binom n k$.